# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'abc' of undefined Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, object, typescript

I have a input type file HTML element and want to upload and read a JSON file and store the file's object content in a local variable. Suppose this is the JSON object I am getting after reading that file :-

```
{
   name:{
        firstName: "Name1",
        lastName: "Name2"
   }
}
```

Now, I want to store this object in a variable after reading the file,

```
private jsondata = {};

readfile(eve){
    let reader:any,
    target:EventTarget;
    reader= new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(eve:any) {
        this.jsondata['json_def'] = JSON.parse(eve.target.result);

        console.log(this.json_def);
    }
    reader.readAsText(eve.target.files[0]);
}
```

This is the error I am receiving in console when I upload it:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'json_def' of undefined
at FileReader.reader.onload (create-model.component.ts:135)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:154)
at FileReader.<anonymous> (zone.js:132)
```

And I am not getting the exact reason of this error. Please someone help. Thanks.

Comment: Try an arrow function for `reader.onload` to preserve the `this` context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the `reader.onload` is not the object's context. So it haven't any variable with name `jsondata`. You can use `arrow function` to preserve your context to the object.

```
reader.onload = (eve:any) => {
    this.jsondata['json_def'] = JSON.parse(eve.target.result);

    console.log(this.json_def);
}
```

Comment: Because of not having this arrow, I was getting error. Thanks for reminding !!